# A PDE Exercise on the Maximum Principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I got this question as an exercise. I gave it a try and I'm sure I did well so far but I got to a point where I couldn't progress anymore. Can anyone help me with how to proceed with my solution or give me a new solution from the beginning?

Exercise: let $u$ be a harmonic function defined in a domain $\Omega$.
If $u$ attains a local maximum in $\Omega$ Prove that $u$ is constant.

My solution:

since $u$ attains local maximum in $\Omega$ then $\exists B_r\left(x_0\right)$ s.t $m=u\left(x_0\right )=\max _{x \in B_r\left(x_0\right)} u(x)$
Since $u$ is a harmonic bounded function on a bounded domain $B_r\left(x_0\right)$ then by Strong maximum principle. $u=m$ in $B_r\left(x_0\right)$

Now, we want to show that $u=m$ in $\Omega$??

Comment: The statement that you want to prove is commonly called the strong maximum principle. I find it strange that you are using the "strong maximum principle" to show that.

Comment: Do you know anything about $Ω$ ?